# How to fix UTF encoding for whitespaces?

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, utf-8, ascii

In my C# code, I am extracting text from a PDF document. When I do that, I get a string that's in UTF-8 or Unicode encoding (I'm not sure which). When I use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(src);` to convert it into a byte array, I notice that the whitespace is actually two characters with byte values of 194 and 160.

For example the string "CLE action" looks like

```
[67, 76, 69, 194 ,160, 65 ,99, 116, 105, 111, 110]
```

in a byte array, where the whitespace is 194 and 160... And because of this `src.IndexOf("CLE action");` is returning -1 when I need it to return 1.

How can I fix the encoding of the string?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`194 160` is the UTF-8 encoding of a `NO-BREAK SPACE` codepoint (the same codepoint that HTML calls `&nbsp;`).

So it's really not a space, even though it looks like one.  (You'll see it won't word-wrap, for instance.)  A regular expression match for `\s` would match it, but a plain comparison with a space won't.

To simply replace NO-BREAK spaces you can do the following:

```
src = src.Replace('\u00A0', ' ');
```

Comment: How can I replace a non-breaking space with an ordinary space?

Comment: @omega: src = src.Replace('\u00A0', ' ');

Comment: More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Answer (score 5):

Interpreting `\xC2\xA0` (=`194, 160`) as UTF8 actually yields `\xA0` which is unicode *non-breaking space*. This is a different character than ordinary space and thus, doesn't match ordinary spaces. You have to match against the non-breaking space or use fuzzy-matching against any whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

In UTF8 character value c2 a0 (194 160) is defined as NO-BREAK SPACE. According to ISO/IEC 8859 this is a space that does not allow a line break to be inserted. Normally text processing software assumes that a line break can be inserted at any white space character (this is how word wrap is normally implemented). You should be able to simply do a replace in your string of the characters with a normal space to fix the problem.

Comment: How can I write the string replace function?

Comment: @omega: src = src.Replace('\u00A0', ' ');