# Replace method not working for escaped char '\xA0' in C#

Tags: c#, replace, escaping

I'm trying to replace '\xA0' character in a string to be blank or worst case a space. 
This code does compile and run, but it won't replace ***nbsp*** character with a space.

```
string line = Stream.ReadLine();
line = line.Replace('\xA0', ' ');
```

Does anyone know an alternative solution or had this issue?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that character is \xA0?

Comment: [It isn't](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JCk3gk). You should inspect the individual characters of the string to find out what it really is, then work back to find whatever encoding issues you might have.

Comment: The problem is most likely not there. You need to go back to your `StreamReader` and make sure you initialize it with the correct encoding.

Comment: How is the problem in the SteamReader? I can read the exact same data in Notepad++ so doesn't make sense..

Comment: Notepad++ does autodetection of the text encoding. `StreamReader` doesn't.

Comment: @Nyerguds can you elaborate on your explanation.

Comment: [Here you go](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Answer (score 1):

I found a reasonable solution to this question. So I convert the &nbsp � character into a int (65533) so I use that value and use the ToChar() method to get my character and then replace using that character.

```
        string line = Stream.ReadLine();
        char SpecNBSPChar = Convert.ToChar(65533);
        line = line.Replace(SpecNBSPChar , ' ');
```

[image: SpecNBSPChar Replace]

After the string replace method.
[image: Proof it worked]

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13992998) thread can you try?

```
line.Replace('\u00A0', ' ');
```

OK, i am trying to redeem myself here. What about using a Regex? Like this:

```
string text = " Ph0b0x � ";
string result = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^\x00-\x7F]+", "");
Console.WriteLine(text);
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

My results:

> Ph0b0x �
>
> Ph0b0x

Regex pattern found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/150078/1340152)

Comment: `'\u00A0'` and `'\xA0'` [are equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175482/what-is-the-difference-between-using-u-and-x-while-representing-character-lite), so this won't help.

Comment: Ph0b0x thanks for effort but I did try that thread before posting this question. Doesn't work :(

Comment: @Jtuck can you please try with the code i just added?